# Declare an array

Tags: c++, arrays

Hi there so I'm having some confusion with an assignment,

> a. Declare an array alpha of 50 components of type int.
>
> b. Initialize each component of alpha to -1.

So what I did was for declaring the array

```
    For( int I = 0; i < 50; I++);
```

Is this declaring the array correctly, and then for initializing each components of alpha to -1, I'm not sure what that means! Any help?

Comment: The code given is not valid C++, and therefore cannot be a valid declaration for an array.

Comment: This is part of how you might initialize the array, though don't uses capital letters for your for loop nor mix them with your vars.  This does not declare an array though.

Comment: _`For( int I = 0; i < 50; I++);`_ That's not too far from valid c++ syntax like: `for( int I = 0; I < 50; I++);` but pretty useless with out a loop body.

Comment: You need to talk with your instructor.  Any examples provided here will give you the answer to your assignment.  We prefer *you* to come up with the answer by thinking.

Comment: Thank you everyone i ended up figuring it out after a couple hours of reading and what not!

Answer (score -2):

**Updated**

This is the correct way to create an integer array with 20 slots.

```
int foo[20];
```

This is how a `for` loop should look:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    // do whatever you want here
}
```

Comment: The array is to be called alpha, each value is to be -1.

Comment: Evan, I believe we were attempting to have OP do this, though there is just enough wrong in your answer that it is still a learning experience to figure out why (or get a zero if turned in directly.)

Comment: Uhm what please? Is this _"An array: ... Loop ..."_ a [Kōan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C5%8Dan)?

Comment: Declaring an array, and a for loop example. My thought was to give the OP the basic idea, just change the for loop (variable names, and inside the loop.) I wasn't trying to completely give the solution. Also the 50 was just a coincidence, I noticed that after I posted...

Comment: int alpha[50]; // declaring alpha
           for (int i = 0; i<50; i++)
           alpha[i] = -1; // saying each component of alpha is -1

          cout << alpha[0]; // the first component, 0 because its before 1

          alpha[24] = 62; //declaring 25 to equal 62

          alpha[9] = 3 * alpha[14] + 10;

Comment: Try:     int alpha[50]; // declaring alpha 

    // this loops 50 times
    for (int i = 0; i<50; i++) {

        
        alpha[i] = -1; // sets all alpha values to -1 

    }